# Is this Active Record (2.3) query correct and complete?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I have some associated models (Rails 2):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :proposals, :dependent => :destroy  
end

class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :proposal_sections, :dependent => :destroy
end

class ProposalSection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :proposal
end
```

In action I want to return all associated with User data. I'm using this query:

```
User.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", params[:id]], :include => [:proposals,   {:proposals => :proposal_sections}])
```

Is this query correct and complete ?
Thank You for answers.

Comment: Does it work for you in `script/console`?

Comment: Yes, console output is correct.

Comment: Okay, so? What's the problem if it works?